# Is it safe and theorotically correct to heat a bar magnet using an open fire/furnace, provided conditions given below?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, temperature

For a project, I will have to heat a bar magnet to any temperature above 40 degree celsius. For this, can I place the magnet over an open fire --like one in a furnace-- for 20 minutes or so to achieve the required temperature?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "theoretically correct", but if all you need is 40 degrees, (i.e. just above body temperature) leaving it in hot water is probably good enough, probably heat the magnet more consistently and make monitoring the temperature easier. Boiling water could also give you a fixed temperature that could be very easily reproduced many times.

Answer (score 1):

You will get most likely get uneven heating that is hard to reproduce - so I would say "no, that is not a good approach". Using a thermal bath like @BySymmetry suggested is much better - or wrap some resistive wire around it and run a known current through it for a known time. The key to good experiments is control and repeatability - your open fire solution appears to offer neither.